# Bloomberg data not populating before vba has finished running

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I know similar questions have been asked in the past, but looking through those posts, I haven't been able to find a solution to the following issue.

I have 2 subs that use Bloomberg API formulas. In the second (Setup_2) the variable LastRow1 is dependent on Setup_1 having populated to work properly.

Using checkStatus_1 and checkStatus_2 I can run each of the 2 setup subs independently, but when I try to create a separate sub calling them, it doesn't work, as the data that LastRow1 depends on isn't there.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Sub Setup_1()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Returns")
    ws1.Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=BDS(Control!B4,""INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST"",""END_DATE_OVERRIDE"",TEXT($A$1,""YYYYMMDD""))"
    ws1.Cells(1, 4).Formula = "=BDH(A2&"" Equity"",""DAY_TO_DAY_TOT_RETURN_GROSS_DVDS"",$B$1,$A$1,""dir=h"")"
    ws1.Cells(3, 4).Formula = "=BDH(A3&"" Equity"",""DAY_TO_DAY_TOT_RETURN_GROSS_DVDS"",$B$1,$A$1,""dir=h"",""dts=h"")"
    checkStatus_1
End Sub

Sub Setup_2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Returns")
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ws1.Cells(3, 4).Formula = "=BDH(A3&"" Equity"",""DAY_TO_DAY_TOT_RETURN_GROSS_DVDS"",$B$1,$A$1,""dir=h"",""dts=h"")"
    ws1.Cells(3, 4).AutoFill Destination:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(3, 4), ws1.Cells(LastRow1, 4))
    checkStatus_2
End Sub

Sub Setup_3()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Returns")
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim LastCol1 As Long
    Dim LCol As String
    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol1 = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LCol = Split(Cells(, LastCol1).Address, "$")(1)
    ws1.Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=(STDEV.S(D2:" & LCol & "2)*SQRT(252))/100"
    ws1.Cells(2, 3).AutoFill Destination:=ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 3), ws1.Cells(LastRow1, 3))
End Sub

Sub checkStatus_1()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Returns")
    Set rng = Application.Union(ws1.Cells(2, 1), ws1.Cells(1, 4), ws1.Cells(3, 4))
    For Each c In rng
        If "#N/A Requesting Data..." = c Or "#N/A Invalid Securiity" = c Then
            Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")), "checkStatus_1"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c    
End Sub

Sub checkStatus_2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Returns")
    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(3, 4), ws1.Cells(LastRow1, 4))
    For Each c In rng
        If "#N/A Requesting Data..." = c Then
            Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")), "checkStatus_2"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c    
End Sub
```

Comment: In your `Setup_3` you calculate `lastRow` in column 1 and `lastColumn` in row 1: Are these the best column and row to find the last used row and column? You have a typo "Securiity". In your check `If "#N/A ...` you could add an `Else`-Statement to start your "Setup_3", if there are no missing values any more.

Comment: If your Bloomberg results don't refresh, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46760475/10908769

Comment: Row and column 1 are the ones i need to use.
The issue i think is that the formula:
 ws1.Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=BDS(Control!B4,""INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST"",""END_DATE_OVERRIDE"",TEXT($A$1,""YYYYMMDD""))" 
is entered in one cell and when complete it populates data in a number of rows beneath the cell with the formula, but only once the macro finishes. This data is hard coded and doesn't contain ""#N/A Requesting Data..."" while it is calculating,  so i dont think the data refresh info is going to help. Can i have sub 1 run and then after a time period run sub 2, without using a 3rd sub to do it?